# Getting null pointer exception while converting JSON String to List using ObjectMapper

Tags: java, jackson

I have a JSON string which is a list of String

```
String jsonString = "['String1','String2','String3']";
```

I am trying to convert it into a List

```
List<String> list = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, List.class);
```

But it is giving me java.lang.NullPointerException

Can any one help me in finding out what is wrong with it?

Edit 2 : Keeping the original post and removing things which may confuse others.

Comment: I think the value of jsonString is actually not a JSON.

Comment: I tried [\"String1\",\"String2\",\"String3\"] yet it is not working

Comment: I am only getting Null pointer exception nothing else

Comment: i did that and i have attacked the image of stacktrace in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried with double quotes ?

```
String jsonString = "[\"String1\",\"String2\",\"String3\"]";
List<?> list = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, List.class);
```

Simple quote is not valid

Comment: I tested it before pasting it though... How strange.

Answer (score 3):

String jsonString = "['String1','String2','String3']"; is not JSON format.